# Enum type variable declarations in C

Tags: c, enums, declaration

I declared this enum type in C :

```
enum months { JAN = 1, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN,
              JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC } ;
```

When I try to create a variable of type months in `main()` with:

```
months month;
```

It gives the following error:

> unknown type 'months'

But when I declare it like this:

```
enum months { JAN = 1, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN,
              JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC } month;
```

It works fine. I thought both ways were valid, so why is there an error?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap a `typedef` around it, otherwise you can access it by stating that it's an `enum`.

Example:

```
typedef enum { JAN = 1, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN,
          JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC } months;
months month;
```

Or

```
enum months { JAN = 1, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN,
          JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC };
enum months month;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
months month;
```

you have to write

```
enum months month;
```

The other way is to define a typedef for the enumeration. For example

```
typedef enum months { JAN = 1, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN,
              JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC } months;
```

and then you may write

```
months month;
```